# Initializing and creating an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, undefined

I want to make an array w[i][j] where each w[i][j] is itself an array of numbers.
If I try to do it naively by declaring an empty array w
and assigning variable by looping through it I get the error:

```
const w : Array<Array<Array<number>>> = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < N; j++){
        w[i][j] = [1,2,3];
        }
    }


TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined.
```

Instead I am forced to initialze each element of the array to be empty, using the below code. Only after doing this am I able to make the array with no problems. This can't be the best practice. What am I misunderstanding and what should I write instead?

```
const w : Array<Array<Array<number>>> = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < N; i++){
        w[i] = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < N; j++){
        w[i][j] = [];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you have to create the array in order to add things to it. Not sure why you think that's a misunderstanding. If you had assigned `w` to be `null` would you expect to be able to add any items to it?

Comment: This is due to the fact, that JS doesn't implement multidimensional arrays, you can only emulate those with nested arrays, which requires every array being defined before referring it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `w[i]` is not set when you are trying to set `w[i][j]`.

## Fix

Do an init or load in the loop e.g.

```
const N = 5;
const w: Array<Array<Array<number>>> = [];
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  w[i] = w[i] || [];
  for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    w[i][j] = [1, 2, 3];
  }
}

console.log(w); // All good
```